# Permutation or Combination?

Tags: probability

I am a bit confused, if I have 2 football teams, and the results are three (1: home win, 2: away win and X: draw), I can see that the possibilities for these teams results are 9, which formula (permutation or combination) to be used here to get 9 as a result?
[image: This is done in excel]

Comment: Sorry consider these Possibilities:A1B1, A1B2, A1BX, A2B2, A2B1, A2BX, AXBX, AXB1, AXB2

Comment: $3^2=9$. The number of combinations (3) to the power of the number of teams (2),

Comment: Thanks @SvenHohenstein , does it mean that if teams were 8, the formula would be 3^8 = 6,561?

Answer (score 0):

This case is not about permutation or combination.
What you are basically doing here is a cartesian product between 2 sets : A and B-the teams.
Each set has 3 elements in it: {1,2,x}
The outcome of the cartesian product is the product of the sets' cardinality: 3 x3=9
Yes in case of 8 teams it will be: 3 times 3 eight time i.e. 3^8

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Yousri's comment:

A permutation tells you how many ways you can choose k items from n total items, if the order of those chosen items matters. A combination tells you how many ways you can choose k items from n total items, where the order of the chosen items doesn't matter. Your question does not have to deal with combinations or permutations -- it has to deal with cartesian products.

The number of possible team results when there are two teams (A, B) and three possibilities (home win, away win, draw) is (the number of possible results for the first game) $\times$ (the number of possible results for the second game) = 3 $\times$ 3 = 9.

If you have 8 teams, then you would have $3^8$ possible results.

Finally, say there were 6 teams and 5 possible game results (A wins, B wins, A forfeits, B forfeits, A and B tie). Then there are $5^6$ possible game results.